# Is there a modern way to preserve WebView state in a Fragment on orientation change?

Tags: android

I know this is a common question. I've viewed dozens of permutations of this question, most of them from years ago. I gather this doesn't work so well anymore.

I know I could set the activity configChanges property. However, this is just one Fragment in an Activity that manages over a dozen other Fragments. It's not ideal to potentially break the rest of the way the app works for the sake of this one Fragment that needs different handling.

setRetainInstance() doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Perhaps that just doesn't work for WebViews in a Fragment. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/cWnxkQ8RLeY/RA1n77EDeR8J

Perhaps webView.saveState worked in the past, but it doesn't seem to anymore. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState(android.os.Bundle) "Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView."

It seems easy enough to manage WebViews in an Activity ,but not a Fragment. Any suggestions?